# fetch type in JPA

Tags: hibernate, jpa, fetch

I'm using JPA, jboss 7A.. This is old problem so i don't show all of code and stackTrack  `Caused by: org.hibernate.loader.MultipleBagFetchException: cannot simultaneously fetch multiple bags`
This is error caused by my code in a entity:

```
@ManyToMany(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(
        name="post_rel_component"
        , joinColumns={
            @JoinColumn(name="post_post_id", nullable=false)
            }
        , inverseJoinColumns={
            @JoinColumn(name="component_component_id", nullable=false)
            }
        )
    private List<Component> components;

    //bi-directional many-to-one association to User
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="post_username", nullable=false)
    private User user;

    //bi-directional many-to-many association to Tag
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy="posts", fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    private List<Tag> tags;
```

I found three solutions to overcome this problem on internet. I fixed by changing `private List<Tag> tags` to `private Set<Tag> tags`. But i don't really understand what causes this problem. most of webpages show how to fix it but don't mention what causes this problem. Can you show why?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is due to Hibernate specific bug https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-1718 which does not exist in other JPA providers.  Just a quick read of the bug suggests that it is a limitation with joining two collections/lists, which occurs by default when marking the collections as eager.  The bug lists other workarounds.

Comment: do you mean if i use Hibernate (in jboss), i have to accept that limitation. And i have to overcome that limitation by changing List type to Set type or another way.

Answer (score 0):

This is just my guess..

Imagine a SQL resultset that fetches posts joined by components and tags -- it might look something like this

```
p.id c.id t.id
1    10   101
1    20   101
1    10   102
1    20   102
```

Read: post 1 is related to two components (10 & 20) and two tags (101 & 102).

Based on this resultset Hibernate has to compose an object graph. Using List Hibernate has to search the list first if the element has previously been added (or maybe it doesn't even bother doing this so you end up with duplicates). So I'm guessing performance(& maybe correctness)-wise forcing user to use Set made sense.

There might be other complicated reason I don't yet know..